# ID needed for one mathematician in group photo

Tags: ho.history-overview, knot-theory

The photo below was taken at MSRI in 1984 and MSRI has asked me to try to find out (on behalf of Lou Kauffman, Sofia Lambropoulou and Martha Jones) the identity of the mathematician farthest left, in front of the blackboard [ANSWERED: Michio Jimbo]. The remaining names are, from left to right, Antony Wassermann, Frederick Goodman, Timothy Ziman, Ruth Lawrence, Vaughan Jones, Daniel Freed, and Jim Lepowsky. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Silvio Levy

Librarian Emeritus, MSRI
[image]

Comment: Many of the people in the photo are alive and seem to be very active. Have you asked them?

Comment: I met him 20 years later, but that guy on the left looks like he might be a young Akio Kawauchi.

Comment: FWIW, this is a photo of Ryan's suggestion, Akio Kawauchi, from 1987: https://opc.mfo.de/detail?photo_id=5387&would_like_to_publish=1

Comment: Kawauchi tells me he was not in Berkeley in 1984 and suggests it's more likely to be Tsuyoshi Kobayashi.

Comment: [Nara has a more recent](https://www.nara-wu.ac.jp/math/personal/tsuyoshi/profile.htm) photo of Tsuyoshi Kobayashi. His paper "PRIMITIVE LINKS OF NON-SINGULAR MORSE-SMALE FLOWS ON THE SPECIAL SEIFERT FIBERED MANIFOLDS", received November 30, 1983 and published in Topology and Its Applications 20 (1985) 67--78 indicates a "Present address" as MSRI. This adds a data supporting what Ryan says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to all who replied.  I wrote to Kobayashi and he said it's not him. I've now heard from MSRI that it's Michio Jimbo, though they didn't tell me the source.  I'll modify the description accordingly.